# ¿Como puedo usar el protocolo TLSv1.2 en Java 6, sin actualizar la version de java a 8?

Tags: seguridad, https, java-6, connection

Estoy tratando de consultar un endpoint con protocolo de seguridad HTTPS:// desde un cliente en Java 6(eh leído que actualizando la versión de Java a 8 se soluciona, pero **no me es posible actualizar la versión** por que esto impactaría otras funcionalidades del sistema), el sistema esta corriendo en un servidor IBM (WebSphere) y al tratar de conectarme a dicho endpoint me arroja la siguiente excepción :

```
Connection resetjava.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:422)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:534)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:486)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
at Test.main(Test.java:31
```

Comment: Adjunta el código que te genera el error.

Answer (score 2):

oficialmente JAVA 6 no tiene soporte para TLS 1.2 .

una alternativa es implementar la libreria, puedes revisar [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6/61115302#61115302)

TLSv1.1 is available for Java 1.6 from update 111 onwards [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https)

Answer (score 2):

Afortunadamente encontré la solución a mi problema, les comparto la guía para agregar el protocolo al servidor y tenga soporte para protocolos TSLv1.2 con Java 6

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/steps-find-ssl-tls-configuration-settings-openpages-deployed-ibm-websphere

espero les sea de utilidad

Saludos